# android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity Cannot Be Imported to Android Studio

Tags: android

This error is reported after the project is created. I tried a lot of things, but it didn't work.

[image]

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.test"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like your trying to use an older version. Update Android studio to its newest stable version and make sure you migrate to Androidx

Answer (score 1):

1. Update your **Android Studio** to the latest version
2. Update your `compileSdkVersion` & `targetSdkVersion` to the latest API[currently **30**]
3. And then from Android studio Migrate your project to `AndroidX` [image]
4. And finally sync and rebuild your project.